# Nautilus search for Artist Albums, Artist name and other Music Metadata

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, music

Is there a way to make Nautilus Search Engine look for Music Metadata like Artist name, Album, Year, Composers,etc... and make it show the results according these Metadata?

I am interested mostly for mp3 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the ability rather easily by downloading a python script: http://pastebin.com/zN69twVP

Discovered through the inimitable resource that is the ArchWiki:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Files#Music_files_metadata_in_list_view

**EDIT:**

You can also add the functionality using WebUpd8's PPA:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/add-pdf-audio-and-exif-metadata-to.html